# Fontawesome 5.13.0 doesn't work in visNetwork

Tags: r, visnetwork

While fontawesome 4.7.0 works smoothly, setting `version = "5.13.0"` doesn't work.
From the documentation:

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, group = c("B", "A", "B"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(2,3))

visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "A", shape = "icon", icon = list(code = "f0c0", size = 75)) %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "B", shape = "icon", icon = list(code = "f007", color = "red")) %>%
  visLegend() %>%
  addFontAwesome(version = "5.13.0")
```

results in
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add :    `face = "'Font Awesome 5 Free'"` in `icon=list()`
Here an exemple :

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "A", shape = "icon", 
      icon = list(face = "'Font Awesome 5 Free'", code = "f0c0", size = 75)) %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "B", shape = "icon", 
      icon = list(face = "'Font Awesome 5 Free'", code = "f007", color = "red")) %>%
  addFontAwesome(version = "5.13.0")
```